# Why does \rput(0,0) translate my picture?

Tags: pstricks

Using rput, I noticed it misplaces my objects. By testing, I found two strange behaviours:

1. `\rput(0,0) { object }` moves my objects a little bit. Doing latex on the following code:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{pst-all}
   \begin{document}
   \psset{xunit=.5pt,yunit=.5pt,runit=.5pt}
   \begin{pspicture}(350,150)
   \rput(0,0) {
   \pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]
   {
   \newpath
   \moveto(75,150)
   \lineto(65,125)
   \lineto(75,135)
   \lineto(85,125)
   \closepath
   }
   }
   \pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red]
   {
   \newpath
   \moveto(75,150)
   \lineto(65,125)
   \lineto(75,135)
   \lineto(85,125)
   \closepath
   }
   \end{pspicture}
   \end{document}
   ```

   produces a red arrow over green arrow, but one can see the green arrow slightly misplaced.
2. `\rput(0,0) { { object } }` moves it even more. Example:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{pst-all}
   \begin{document}
   \psset{xunit=.5pt,yunit=.5pt,runit=.5pt}
   \begin{pspicture}(350,150)
   \rput(0,0) {
   {
   \pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]
   {
   \newpath
   \moveto(75,150)
   \lineto(65,125)
   \lineto(75,135)
   \lineto(85,125)
   \closepath
   }
   }
   }
   \pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red]
   {
   \newpath
   \moveto(75,150)
   \lineto(65,125)
   \lineto(75,135)
   \lineto(85,125)
   \closepath
   }
   \end{pspicture}
   \end{document}
   ```

`latex --version` gives:

```
    pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014/Arch Linux)
    kpathsea version 6.2.0
```

Why is that, how to fix it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You are inserting some unneeded space in your 15th line of code. It should be `\closepath}%`

Comment: Note that if you use two `\rput`s, there is no problem.

Comment: @Bernard: it has nothing to do with one or two `\rput`

Comment: @Herbert: I've read your limpid explanation. There remains that using two \rput avoids unwanted space. It was only an observation.

Comment: @Bernard if you use two `\rput` (with spurious spaces in each) it just means that you get the unwanted displacement in both cases, so the arrows line up, but that just means they are both wrong, not that the problem has gone.

Comment: I see I thought there was a spurious space between the two \pscustom. In any cases when I tested, adding a second \rput, everything was fine. Probably Ideleted the spurious space with even realising I did…

Comment: @Bernard: Adding second rput 'solves' the problem for 'this' example. But, in fact, it does not solve the problem: when putting some text in the picture (using rput of course!), it is placed in different coordinates than these arrows (i.e. rput(0,0) misplaces these arrows and rput(0,0) does not misplace the text!). In general I guess there are many other cases when rput(0,0) does not move anything, as Herbert's answer suggests.

Answer (score 4):

Use `

```
\rput(...){%
  ... %
}
```

without additional spaces! For example:

```
\rput(0,0){%
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green]
{
\newpath
\moveto(75,150)
\lineto(65,125)
\lineto(75,135)
\lineto(85,125)
\closepath
}%
}
```

Otherwise you'll get two unwanted spaces. `\pscustom` itself removes spaces but the argument of `\rput` is handled as default TeX and will keep spaces.

Comment: Nice. If you don't mind, could you explain me why rput[Br](0,0) makes the displacement and rput[Bl](0,0) does not? (I have found such workaround)

Comment: In fact, I use code like `\rput(200,0) { \input{file.pst} }` and the code for arrows and other stuff is in `file.pst`. And this file may be large, so I am not keen on editing it by hand, adding `%` at the end of many lines. I guess I could add `%` at the end of every line, yeah?

Comment: Use `\rput(200,0) {\input{file.pst}}` without spaces before and after the `\input` macro

Comment: This does not help.

Comment: then you have some more spaces in the `file.pst`

Comment: Yes, as I have written before.

Answer (score 0):

Using a left anchor

```
\rput[Bl] (0,0) { 
    (...)
}
```

does the trick (`tl` and `bl` are also possible instead of `Bl`).

Also deleting unnecessary spaces as in

```
\rput(...){%
    ... %
}
```

solves the problem, but is not convenient when including external files, which would have to contain no extra spaces.